# React BrowserRouter won't go to default route

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I have routing code in my react app where when a user is not logged in, they go to the login route. When they pass auth (using Auth0) the url goes to `localhost:8100` (without slash), and doesn't redirect to `/chat`.

```
{isAuthenticated ? <>
                  <Route exact path="/chat">
                    <ChatTab/>
                  </Route>
                  <Route exact path="/directory">
                    <DirectoryTab/>
                  </Route>
                  <Route exact path="/">
                    <Redirect to="/chat" />
                  </Route>
                </>
                :
                <Route exact path="/login">
                  <Login/>
                </Route>}
```

Comment: maybe, console.log to see if it gets to the part `<Redirect to="/chat" />`. Because it could be tricky sometimes when you redirect to other page